# Collision detection between characters in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics

I am working on 3D fighting game and I am using Unity3D as my game engine. I have a scene, two characters who work very fine and I can control it with my keyboard. But now the problem is in the collision detection.

I have used capsule colliders on my characters and also rigidbody gravity. Now when both these players collide the collision can be detected easily but due to the collision my character will fall down and is not able to stand, just like a capsule. I want to create some realistic effects just like other games have. Is there way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a Mesh Collider, but that does not work for animated models.

Here are some suggestions:

> **Collision for Animated Characters**
>
> Note: The mesh collider does not animate. This means that if you want accurate 1:1 collisions for
> animated characters, it will need a series of colliders parented to
> each joint roughly the same shape as the character.
>
> Another way to do
> this is to make a ragdoll out of the character and turn off (or
> remove) the rigidbody components. If you just want generic collisions
> for humanoid characters, you may use a Character Controller (below).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use primitive colliers because two mesh colliers can never collide with each other.

If you want to make realistic interactions... you should use animations and IK in Unity... its the best way...

For more collision related issues check this : https://youtu.be/Bg73o9JH53c